# proper way to instantiate entities

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a question about the instantiation of entity in page level. It's asp.net webform codebehind.
One way is like below:

```
private Entities _context;

public Entities context
{
    get
    {
        return _context;
    }
}
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    _context = new Entities();
    base.OnPreInit(e);
}
```

Another way I just add `var context = new Entities();` to each method if I need update context;

Or I am thinking claim  like this: `private Entities _context;` Then in each method I just update it and do `context.SaveChanges()` directly

I am confusing, which is correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer instantiating a new context every time, surrounding it with a `using` block.

If I need to call a method multiple times in one transaction, I will create an overload that takes the context as a parameter.

```
private void SaveData(Entities context, object data)
{
  context.Data.Add(...);
}

public void SaveData(object data)
{
  using(var context = new Entities())
  {
    SaveData(context, data);
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}

public void SaveMultipleData(IEnumerable<object> data)
{
  using(var context = new Entities())
  {
    foreach(var d in data)
    {
      SaveData(context, data);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aducci. I am wondering if there is any benefit of putting object(like eneity) to property.

Comment: @AgLong - Putting the context in a property will make it easier to access the context from any method. I am not sure when the context will be disposed, but it probably won't matter. This comes down to your personal preference